# How to call a variable and prevent to run another module?

Tags: python, api

I am kind of new in python, trying to develop an user interaction with an API.

In this API I have to authenticate first and then with a token received I can do multiple things,

I have a module `authfile.py` that returns a cookie which is in a variable

```py
url = "https://172.16.1.77:8089/api"

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'Connection': 'close',
}

def auth(self, url, headers):
        
        data = '{"request": {"action":"challenge","user":"apiuser","version":"1.0"}}'

        # First send the challenge.

        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data, verify=False)

        # Get the challenge into variable.

        a = response.json()
        b = a['response']
        c = b['challenge']

        print("This is the challenge number: " + c)

        # Getting the challenge with the Password with MD5
        e = input("Please enter the Password\n")
        user = c+e
        h = hashlib.md5(user.encode())
        md = h.hexdigest()
        print("This is the Token: " + md)

        datas = '{"request":{"action":"login", "token":"' + str(md) + '", "url":"' + str(url) + '" , "user": "cdrapi"}}'

        #Send the token to get the Cookie

        response2 = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=datas, verify=False)

        #Getting the cookie into a variable
        global cookie
        f = response2.json()
        g = f['response']
        cookie = g['cookie']

        print("This is the Cookie: " +cookie)

        return cookie

cookie = auth(url, headers)
```

So I have another file that I use to apply some changes, it will need to be in a different module since the `applychanges()` functions will be called many times

`applychanes.py`:

```py
from authfile import url, headers, cookie
import requests

def changes():
    while True:
            q = (input("Are you sure you would like to apply changes?\nPlease enter only Y for Yes and N for No\n").lower())
            if q.lower() not in ("y", "n"):
                print("This is not a valid entry")
            if q == "y":
                postta = '{"request":{"action":"applyChanges", "cookie":"' + str(cookie) + '"}}'
                format_to_json = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=postta, verify=False)
                jsonresponse = format_to_json.json()
                                        # Get the response in a variable
                presponse = jsonresponse['response']
                                        # Get the status code into a variable
                codestatus = jsonresponse['status']
                                        # Print the reponse
                print(presponse)
                print(codestatus)
                print("The changes has been applied")
                break
                    
            if q == "n":
                print("NO changes has been made")
                break
            else:
                continue
    return q
```

When I call the Cookie, the auth file is excecuted again changing the Cookie and the changes will not be applied since the new cookie means a new session**

How do I call a variable preventing to run the function?

On the Main program the auth MUST be excecuted before anything else.

Comment: [`if __name__ == "__main__":`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/10824407) ?

Comment: Hi Olvin, I have been tryng to get this but I am unsure where to put it or how it should be structurated the code, WOuld you give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

> when I call the cookie, the authfile is executed again

If I read you right here, you mean than when you do `import authfile` or `from authfile import cookie`, `authfile` gets evaluated again, and the cookie changes.

This is impossible, unless you are using `reload` (or a reload-like trick, like `del sys.modules["authfile"]`.  Python will *only ever evaluate an imported module once*: after that it just binds a new name to it.*  Thus if your debugging is premised on the idea that importing the same file multiple times is causing the file to be evaluated multiple times, it's based on a misconception, and something else is going wrong.

On the other hand, I could easily be misreading you here!  Do clarify if I'm wrong; I'll check back on this tomorrow [and delete this sentence either way].

In any case, this is probably an instance of a bigger problem: modules are not really for state: that's more what *classes* are for.  Modules just insulate namespaces, but that can have problems if you rely on module-level variables to hold state.  So if you really *do* have a problem with state changing stored in a module, either make a class, to be the 'single source of truth' with respect to this state:

```py
class Authentication:
    def __init__(self, url, headers):
        # put your auth code here
        self._cookie = ...

    @property
    def cookie(self):
        return self._cookie
```

With appropriate methods to refresh the cookie when needed, or possibly with a dict of cookies if you have multiple realms.

If you don't want to do that and you still think something else is modifying your cookie, replace all instances of `cookie` with a `get_cookie()` function defined as:

```py
_cookie = auth(url, headers)
def get_cookie():
    return _cookie
```

That will throw an error when somebody tries to *write* to your cookie.

Note that all this assumes that `cookie` is an immuteable type.  A possible cause of your problem is `cookie` being e.g. a dict or list, and something else modifying that---which will modify the original object.

Lastly, if your problem is simply that you want to define `cookie` in `authfile` but only *generate* it later, wrap it in a function or method on a class (personally I would do this---classes are for state, modules for namespace), and call the method later.  Something like:

```py
class Authentication:
    def __init__(self, url, headers):
        self._url = url
        self._headers = headers

    @staticmethod
    def authenticate(url, headers):
        # your auth fn

    @property
    def cookie(self):
        if not self._cookie:
            self._cookie = self.authenticate(self._url, self._headers)
        return self._cookie

auth = Authentication(url, headers)
```

This will generate the cookie the first time it's accessed.  So import as:

```py
from authfile import auth
...
with auth.cookie as cookie:
   ...
```

*Alright, I don't actually know what happens in the case of circular imports, whether Python 'evaluates' the same file multiple times before bailing.  But it bails, so the question is moot.

Comment: I really have to thank you for all your effort answering this, I will try this tomorrow also haha, however I wanted to clear for a better understanding:
The cookie is not mutable, Once I get it, I hold this on a variable, use it as I wish and in case the cookie is not valid anymore, it will throw an error which I will be handling later.